# Python: Calculate Totals per category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have the following code to generate some random data a calculate a crosstab.

```
import random 
import pandas as pd

# List of years 
years = [2000, 2001, 2003]

# List of categories and statuses 
categories = ['CatA', 'CatB', 'CatC'] 
statuses = ['Active', 'Inactive']

# Empty lists to store the data 
data = []

# Generate random data for each year 
for year in years:
        for _ in range(3):
            category = random.choice(categories)
            status = random.choice(statuses)
            data.append([year, category, status])

# Create a DataFrame to store the data 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Year', 'Category', 'Status'])


#Create crosstab 
cross_tab = pd.crosstab([df.Year, df.Status], df.Category)

#Sum columns 
category_totals = cross_tab.sum(axis=1) 
cross_tab = pd.concat([category_totals, cross_tab], axis=1) 
cross_tab.rename(columns={0: 'Total'}, inplace=True)

#Print 
cross_tab
```

This creates a cross tab with the colums sum, now I also want to add the total of Status for each year, but I am unable to do so:

| Year | Status | Total | CatA | CatB | CatC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | Total | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
|  | Active | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
|  | Inactive | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2001 | Total | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
|  | Active | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|  | Inactive | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2003 | Total | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
|  | Active | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
|  | Inactive | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

With:

```
gender_year_totals = cross_tab.sum(level="Year")
```

I was able to calculuate the totals for Status, but pd.concat() refuses to merge the dataframe, because they have different levels of indexes.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am also very happy to use pd.pivot or pd.groupby, if this makes it easier...

Comment: Small improvement - you can calculate the total column by - `cross_tab = pd.crosstab([df.Year, df.Status], df.Category, margins=True, margins_name='Total')`
And save the `sum columns` part

Answer (score 0):

You can add the total column before using pd.concat (which you do not need) like:

```
#Create crosstab 
cross_tab = pd.crosstab([df.Year, df.Status], df.Category)

#Sum columns 
category_totals = cross_tab.sum(axis=1) 
cross_tab["total"] = category_totals
```

Likewise you can do the following to concat the gender data:

```
gender_year_totals = gender_year_totals.reindex(cross_tab.index,level=0)
pd.concat([cross_tab,gender_year_totals],keys=["original","gender"],axis=1)
```

But be aware that it basically repeats the information for each year. So you might want to insert na-values in some places.